# Jquery .bind() stops working after refresh

Tags: html, jquery, sharepoint

```
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<title>Personal Lines Internal Referral</title>

<style>
    select:required:invalid {
        color: #666;
    }

    option[value=""][disabled] {
        display: none;
    }

    option {
        color: #000;
    }

    div.interestFollowupQuestions {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    (() => {
        'use strict'

        // Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
        // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
        const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')

        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
            form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
                if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    event.stopPropagation()
                }

                form.classList.add('was-validated')
            }, false)
        })

        $(document).ready(function () {
            const isDebugMode = false;
            var blob;
            const lineBreak = '\r\n';

            if (isDebugMode) {
                //Add test data to all fields
                $("#00N3b000004vOvC").val("Star Producer");
                $('#employee_id').val("8675309");
                $("#referrer_relationship").val("ExistingOrProspectiveAJGClient").change();
                $("#referrer_relationshipDetails").prop("disabled", false);
                $("#relationshipDetails").show();
                $("#referrer_relationshipDetails").val("Current commercial lines customer");
                $("#first_name").val("John");
                $("#last_name").val("Smithenson");
                $("#phone").val("847-123-4567");
                $("#street").val("123 Main Berry Avenue");
                $("#city").val("Chicago");
                $("#state_code").val("IL").change();
                $('#BillingPostalCode').val("60601");
                $("#currently_servicing").val("Yes").change();
                $("#interestHome").prop("checked", true);
                $("#residencesOwned").val(2);
                $("#squareFootageLargestResidence").val(3800);
                $("#propertyLocationState").val("IL, WI");
                $("#interestAuto").prop("checked", true);
                $("#numVehiclesToInsure").val(2);
                $("#interestOther").prop("checked", true);
                $(".interestFollowupQuestions").toggle(true).find('input').prop("disabled", false);
                $("#additionalInformation").val("This is an important client of ours, representing $100k in revenue. He is searching for personal insurance for his home, autos, and yacht. His daughter turned 16 and just got her license.");
            }

            **$("#referrer_relationship").bind('change', function () {
                const selectedValue = $(this).val();
                if (selectedValue === "Other" || selectedValue === "ExistingOrProspectiveAJGClient") {
                    $("#referrer_relationshipDetails").prop("disabled", false);
                    $("#relationshipDetails").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#relationshipDetails").hide();
                    $("#referrer_relationshipDetails").prop("disabled", true); //Prevents validation
                }
            });
            
            $("#referrer_relationship").bind('change', function () {
                const selectedValue = $(this).val();
                if (selectedValue === "ExistingOrProspectiveAJGClient") {
                    $("#revenue_estimate").prop("disabled", false);
                    $("#revenueEstimate").show();
                }
                else {
                    $("#revenueEstimate").hide();
                    $("#revenue_estimate").prop("disabled", true); //Prevents validation
                }
            });
            $(".interestCheckbox").bind('change', function () {
                const followupQuestions = $(this).parents(".interestSection").children(".interestFollowupQuestions");
                followupQuestions.toggle(this.checked).find('input').prop("disabled", !this.checked); //Prevents validation
            })**

            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                blob = "";

                //Employee ID
                blob += "Employee ID # " + $('#employee_id').val().trim() + lineBreak;

                //Relationship Details
                blob += "Relationship to referred: " + $("#referrer_relationship option:selected").text().trim();
                if ($("#referrer_relationshipDetails").is(":visible")) blob += " (Detail:" + $("#referrer_relationshipDetails").val() + ")" + lineBreak;
                
                // AJG Account Revenue Estimate
                blob += "AJG Account Revenue Estimate" + $("#revenue_estimate").val().trim() + lineBreak;
                
                //Current PL client
                blob += "Current PL client: " + $("#currently_servicing option:selected").text().trim() + lineBreak;

                //Initial Policy Interest
                blob += "Initial policy interest: ";
                var interestCount = $(".interestCheckbox:checked").length;
                if (interestCount == 0) {
                    blob += "None";
                }
                else {
                    //Initial Policy Interest - Home
                    if ($("#interestHome").prop("checked") == true) {
                        interestCount++;
                        blob += "Home/Condo/Rental ("
                        blob += "Properties: " + $("#residencesOwned").val();
                        blob += ", Largest sq. ft: " + $("#squareFootageLargestResidence").val();
                        blob += ", Property state: " + $("#propertyLocationState").val();
                        blob += ")"
                    }

                    //Initial Policy Interest - Auto
                    if ($("#interestAuto").prop("checked") == true) {
                        if (interestCount > 0) blob += ", ";
                        interestCount++;
                        blob += "Auto (";
                        blob += "Count: " + $("#numVehiclesToInsure").val();
                        blob += ")";
                    }

                    //Initial Policy Interest - Auto
                    if ($("#interestOther").prop("checked") == true) {
                        if (interestCount > 0) blob += ", ";
                        interestCount++;
                        blob += "Other"
                    }
                }
                blob += lineBreak;

                //Additional Information
                blob += "Addt'l info: " + $("#additionalInformation").val().trim();

                blob += lineBreak;

                //AJG Advisor
                blob += "Name of AJG Advisor: " + $("#nameofAJGadvisor").val().trim();

                if (isDebugMode) {
                    alert(blob);
                    alert(blob.length);
                }

                //Place in hidden text area for HTML Form submission
                $("#description").val(blob);
            });
        })

    })()
</script>
```

All of the above changes works in fiddler.js, but the problem starts when i upload the html in Sharepoint .aspx
The whole form works, except the JQuery (#referrer_relationship").bind and (.interestCheckbox").bind.
Bind works on initial page load, but doesnt work after refresh.
Initially i used .change(), but that didnt work at all after upload to Sharepoint(using Shortpoint tool)

Comment: ` but doesnt work after refresh` What is the behavior exactly?

Comment: When the page loads initially, the .bind jquery code works, but when i click on Ctrl+F5(Refresh), it stops working @ryanwebjackson